# all-in-one, audio and video format converter for Android

Tags: android, video, audio, media-converter

In short, something that just does what one would expect such a program to do. (Just convert it so it works on my media player!)

- Free or Paid
- "all-in-one" I mean a program that can convert to and from most common formats like MP3, M4A, WAV, FLAC, automatically introspecting containers like AVI and detecting codecs.
- Optional(Video Editing Features like trim, split, merge, crop)
- Ability to extract audio/video

For Android 9+

Comment: While waiting for answers, be welcome to take a look at my corresponding app lists [here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_video#group_230) and [here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_music_audioedit#group_1038). I don't know which app would fit the bill (not using any of them myself). Be further warned that almost no app in this category comes without trackers, unfortunately…